# Why does Scala's Future.onComplete needs an ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, concurrency

Can't `Promise.complete` just run `Future.onComplete`'s callback, and not go all the way through a `ExecutionContext` and, as I understand it, schedule `Future.onComplete`'s callback for later and potentially run it in another thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your own `ExecutionContext` to `onComplete`, that will run the code on the same thread:

```
val immediateContext: ExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext {
  def execute(runnable: Runnable) {
    runnable.run()
  }
  def reportFailure(cause: Throwable) {}
}
```

You can even make it `implicit`, and for cases where you want the execution to take place in another thread, you can provide `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global` or some other context.

Here is a test, how it works:

```
val immediateContext: ExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext {
  override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = {}
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = {
    println("Executing")
    runnable.run()
    println("Executed")
  }
}

def testContext(): Unit = {
  println("Scheduling on an uncompleted future")
  val p = Promise[Int]()
  println("Scheduling")
  p.future.onComplete { _ => println("Completed") }(immediateContext)
  println("Scheduled")
  p.complete(Success(5))

  println()

  println("Scheduling on an already completed future")
  val p2 = Promise[Int]().complete(Success(5))
  println("Scheduling")
  p2.future.map { n =>
    println("Mapping")
    n * 2
  }(immediateContext).onComplete{
    case Success(n) => println(s"Completed: $n") 
    case _ =>
  }(immediateContext)
  println("Scheduled")

  println()

  println("Using scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global for comparison")
  val p3 = Promise[Int]().complete(Success(5))
  println("Scheduling")
  p3.future.onComplete {
    _ => println("Completed")
  }(concurrent.ExecutionContext.global)
  println("Scheduled")
}
```

Running `testContext()` will print

```
Scheduling on an uncompleted future
Scheduling
Scheduled
Executing
Completed
Executed

Scheduling on an already completed future
Scheduling
Executing
Mapping
Executed
Executing
Completed: 10
Executed
Scheduled

Using scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global for comparison
Scheduling
Scheduled
Completed
```

Answer (score 1):

It's design decision for implementing scala Futures, all operations (map, flatMap, etc...) requires implicit ExecutionContext.

If you'd like to have better thread reusability and less context switches between threads I'd suggest you to take a look at scalaz Task, slightly different abstraction for delayed computations: http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/